# routerLink not render well angular 4.3.x

Tags: angular

I've upgraded to angular 4.3.2.

I have the following span links, the default page is Inbox. When I click on New, the Add page is on/above inbox page, when page is loaded, the inbox page disappears and Add page stays there. Then, when I click on Inbox, the Inbox page is on/above Add page, when page is loaded, the Add page disappears and Inbox page stays there. So I see it's working like stack. How can I do in order to avoid this stack render?

```
<span routerLink="/Inbox">Inbox</span>
<span routerLink="/Add">Add</span>
```

Comment: Replace <span> with <a> ?

Comment: I replaced with <a>, same result

Comment: At this point we will need some code of you... like component(s) class codes, more template, routes configurations. Or a plunker! From your explanation it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: Please open the browser console / devtools and look for errors. An error can prevent a route from being properly unloaded in Angular 4, thus resulting in two components from different routes being shown at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded the web app to angular 4.3.6 and I see it renders well now on Chrome and IE 11, not confirmed on Firefox. It seems it was an angular bug.